# What are the minimum scopes needed in an oauth2.0 to grant a web app access to a user’s google spreadhseets?

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-visualization, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I’m using google visualization charts and timeline to display some data on a simple webpage. 
The data for the charts comes from a google sheet.
The google sheet is set to private and therefore I need an oauth flow to sign in the user before I present the chart.

All users have been given prior access to the spreadsheet.

Now the issue is that it seems that google wants me to ask for over the top permissions from my users to access this chart.

Meaning it requires: 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds

Which asks the user permissions to, I quote “See, edit, delete, all your files in your google dirve”. This is quite scary and unnecesary but it’s the only way I can get this to work.

Shouldn’t this scope be enough https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly ?

Or is the way the Oauth called that’s the issue?

```
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*yourspreadhseetid*/gviz/tq?gid=*yourgid*&headers=1&tqx=responseHandler:handleQueryResponse' + '&access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feed` scope is for version 3 of the sheets API. Yes, you should move towards `/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` as that is version 4 of the API. You can read more about how to migrate [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration).

Comment: Thanks, so I just need to change the scope to the new scope and my query parameter to use the new methods without changing the oauth flow? i.e from docs.google.com... to ...spreadsheets.google.com....?

Comment: Ok, check out here. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization It explicitely states that you need to call the https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds scope.

Comment: Thanks, these docs should probably be updated to V4 of the sheets API.

Comment: Yes they should, still have no idea how to do this after a day of searching online through various forums. I'll try to post another question, maybe someone can help out.

Comment: The documentation demo has been updated to version 4 of the Google Spreadsheets API https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization